# PHP Strict Standards: Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php, standards, strict

i have this error in my cronjobs report

PHP Strict Standards:  Creating default object from empty value in /home/admin/domains/DOMAIN.com/public_html/birthdate.php on line 28
Strict Standards: Creating default object from empty value in /home/admin/domains/DOMAIN.com/public_html/birthdate.php on line 28

And My Codes :

```
28-   $D->user_birthdate = array();
29-   $latest_members_arr = $network->get_user_birthdate();
30-   foreach($latest_members_arr as $usr)
40-   {
41-     $D->user_birthdate[]    = $network->get_user_by_id($usr);
42-   }
43-    $num    = 30;
44-   $D->user_birthdate    = array_slice($D->user_birthdate, 0, $num);
```

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Have you instantiated $D?

Comment: where is $D defined? php tries to create a default-object but $D seems to be empty.

Comment: Then show us the code, how do you instantiate $D?

Comment: You should set your default error level to the highest level, either in php.ini or in your file (similar to `use strict` in perl.)  It would have then immediately complained about D.  High error levels save a lot of time!

Comment: i use $D in my Class network just like bellow : global $C, $D, $page;
 Line 822:                     $D->$k  = $v;
 Line 829:             $D->page    = & $page;
 Line 830:             $D->user    = $to_user;
 Line 831:             $D->subject     = $subject;

Comment: But you do not instantiate it... You should have $D = new stdClass(); before you use anything like $D->...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the top of your code add the below line.

```
$D =  new stdClass();
$D->user_birthdate = array();
```

You get the error because `$D` doesn't exist. You should create a new StdClass object. stdClass is php's generic empty class. [Read more](http://krisjordan.com/dynamic-properties-in-php-with-stdclass).

Given that if your $D object has a specific type(type of object) make sure you use it. 
EG :

```
$D =  new dClass();
```

Here `$D` is a object of Class `dClass()`

Answer (score 2):

Probably $D is null?
Use an array instead:

```
$birth_dates = array();
$latest_members_arr = $network->get_user_birthdate();
foreach($latest_members_arr as $usr)
{
   birth_dates[]    = $network->get_user_by_id($usr);
}
```

Alternatively, consider using the standard class in case $D is null, add this to the top of your code:

```
if (empty($D)) {
$D = new stdClass();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$D` is not defined. It must be set to something using the `new` keyword (or copied from a previously instantiated object) before values can be assigned.